# How to dynamically render dataframes in navset_tab()?

Tags: python, py-shiny

I have a directory that contains `N` entities, and each entity has two datasets called "Input Parameters" and "Mapping Parameters". I've created a way to show each of the entities and a way for the user to page between their datasets, but I cannot render the datasets.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Current setup as reference:

[work so far in desired format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/559we.png)

Code:

```
from shiny import render, run_app, App, reactive, ui
import pandas as pd


data = {
    'Entity 1' : {
        'Input Parameters' : pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]}),
        'Mapping Parameters' : pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
    },
    'Entity 2' : {
        'Input Parameters' : pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]}),
        'Mapping Parameters' : pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
    },
    'Entity 3' : {
        'Input Parameters' : pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]}),
        'Mapping Parameters' : pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
    },
    'Entity 4' : {
        'Input Parameters' : pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]}),
        'Mapping Parameters' : pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
    }
}


app_ui = ui.page_navbar(
    ui.nav('Home', ui.page_fluid(ui.output_ui('display_navpills'))),
    title='App'
)


def server(input, output, session):

    def navpill_controls():
        return [
            ui.nav(
                entity,
                ui.navset_tab(
                    ui.nav('Input Parameters', ui.output_data_frame(f"{entity.replace(' ', '_')}_Input_Parameters")),
                    ui.nav('Mapping Parameters', ui.output_data_frame(f"{entity.replace(' ', '_')}_Mapping_Parameters"))
                )
            )
            for entity in data
        ]
    
    
    @output
    @render.ui
    def display_navpills():
        return ui.navset_pill_list(*navpill_controls())
    
app = App(app_ui, server)
run_app(app)
```

Comment: Think the issue comes down to this - when an event is triggered, Python refers to the output's respective function name to render the object. This poses a problem because the IDs used for the tables are dynamic - but we cannot have dynamic function names. However, the IDs cannot be something like 'input parameters' because this creates duplicate output IDs which shiny does not like. Bit stuck here.

Comment: Figured out how to render one table but not the rest. Involved inserting UI below the dynamic ID with the static ID then rendering the table for the static ID. Thanks @Jan for the edits to reduce reach!